# Get next(); item after sorting with Isotope

Tags: jquery, sorting, jquery-selectors, jquery-isotope

I'm using Isotope to sort latest or popular. There is always an item with the class, ".current" with the jQuery next function can I search for the next element and get the class.

The problem is: after sorting with isotope the next function doesn't work anymore. When I run the script he looks at the html code and not the position. My question is: is there a way to get the item next to the current, even after sorting?

I made a quick [jsFiddle][1]. When you click at Popular, Isotope sorts the items from high to low. The blue item (the item next to .current) isn't the next item anymore but still blue.

I Hope you guys can help me out.

```
 [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/giel/HCKKT/
```

Comment: Do you have an example anywhere..?

Comment: Yes, there is a way, but without seeing the resulting html, we can't tell you what that way is.

Comment: I made a quick jsFiddle. When you click at Popular, Isotope sorts the items from high to low. The blue item (the item next to .current) isn't the next item anymore but still blue.

http://jsfiddle.net/giel/HCKKT/